# How to mux srt subtitles into a video while keeping the multiple audio files using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have been using:

ffmpeg -i "video.mkv" -sub_charenc UTF-8 -i "video.srt" -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 handler="English" -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 "subbed_video.mp4"

But when I do it, I notice only the English audio carries over but the Japanese audio disappears. Is there a way to ensure both carry over? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default ffmpeg only copies one video stream and one audio stream. You need to specify all your streams using 3 -map output options:

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mkv" -sub_charenc UTF-8 -i "video.srt" -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 handler="English" -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 1:s:0 "subbed_video.mp4"
```

Here, I'm assuming that you have only 2 audio tracks (`a:0` and `a:1`) on `video.mkv`.

Comment: Thanks. I used this exact line but now while both audio tracks carry over, the subtitles are not in the output file at all.

Comment: You probably need to map the subtitle stream as well.Try adding `-map 1:s:0` to see if that resolves the second point. Will look into the first issue tomorrow (if nobody else post a solution)